# How can I search Twitter for Tweets containing Quote Marks

Tags: twitter-search

Is there any way, either in the Twitter website, app or using API to search for Tweets that contain quotations?

Specifically in the form " ##any random text here## "

---

If it helps, I really want to find Tweets where people are quoting podcasts

Here is an example https://x.com/JoshuaTCharles/status/1727258105980072127?s=20

The Tweet contains the string  ' "tried to put it out there to test the populace." '

and the string 'open.spotify.com/episode/...'

---

Can you help?